# Handling long expressions

Tags: expression-manipulation

After using `Expand` on the result of a calculation I get a long expression which is a sum of `8654461` terms (nearly 8.7 million). When I `Export`'ed the expression into an ascii txt file (I use Debian 9) its size is 1.3 gb.

My goal is to integrate each term, say with respect to angle `x` from 0 to 2$\pi$. Each term is simple (the reason why I `Expand`'ed in the first place) and easily integrated. However if I feed the entire expanded expression to `Integrate`, after many hours the kernel automatically quits with no output. I believe this is because of memory issues.

My question: **What's an efficient way to manipulate a long expression term-by-term?**

I have an expression which is a sum of terms: `expr=f1[x]+f2[x]+f3[x]+...` I tried extracting each term using `expr[[i]]` and then integrating each term inside a `Table`, but even this doesn't work, meaning it takes forever to integrate even the first term. I observed that it takes long to access `expr[[i]]` when `i` is large (>500). Is there a way to break up the expression easily into a list of terms so that then each element of the list may be accessed quickly? Or is there another way?

Comment: You can break the expression into a list: `lst=List@@expr` You can then split your list into shorter sublists using `lst2=Partition[lst,n]` where n is the length of the sublists. Be careful, it may be necessary to manually create one sublist, and cut it away before the partition operation is applied, such that partition can divide the rest into n equal parts. This may serve to have short lists that you may integrate during the one-day session, while the rest you leave for tomorrow.  You may now apply Integrate to the sublist, say `Map[Integrate[#,{x,a,b},assumptions]&,lst2[[1]] ]`

Comment: Continuation: will integrate each element of the first sublist lst2 from a to b with the assumptions. After you have integrated everything and collected the results into the list listInt you might apply `Plus@@listInt` and get the results. Is it what you wanted? On the other hand, your words that even the first integral takes too long to be evaluated gives me a suspicion that the primary problem is not in the length of the expression but maybe, in integration. I propose that you first check this.

Comment: If `expr` is not itself modified during the evaluation, then there should be no problems accessing its elements, since an expression is (roughly speaking) an array of pointers, which are accessed by their position. Could you provide a minimal example of the code which takes long time to evaluate?

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch That's what I want. Why not post it as an answer? Also each term when given separately is quickly integrated, but when the entire expanded expression is fed in it takes long to evaluate (I checked using `Monitor`). Perhaps `Integrate` tries to simplify before it begins integration and that may be the cause of the delay.

Comment: @Anton.Sakovich Thanks for your comment. My code is long and complicated. You may take the example `sum` in m_goldberg's answer for some very large `n`.

Comment: @Deep There is no need to make the answer, since the response of @m_goldberg does the same job, except that he used a loop and I use mapping. I have one more comment. You did not show your expressions and I do not know, if they may depend on parameters. In the latter case, there can be a situation that in different domains of the parametric space the integral has different values, while in some has no value at all. Typically, in such a situation it takes a long time to evaluate such an integral. If, however, you fix the domain in the parametric space by using `Assumptions`, it is fast

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would like to elaborate on my comment here, because modifying large `List`s in place is a common source of slow-downs.

I would say that the main rule of manipulating long expressions in *Mathematica* is not to allow *Mathematica* to evaluate them more then it is completely necessary. Let us consider the example of @m_goldberg for a large `n`:

```
n = 10^4;
sum = x^Range[n];
Do[sum[[i]] = Integrate[sum[[i]], x], {i, n}] // Timing
(*3.23438, Null}*)
```

It might seem strange, but just changing the head from `List` to `HoldComplete` leads to 40-times less time taken:

```
hsum = HoldComplete @@ sum;
Do[hsum[[i]] = Integrate[hsum[[i]], x], {i, n}] // Timing
(*{0.09375, Null}*)
```

This happens because `HoldComplete` does not check for `UpValues`. Every time *Mathematica* sees a "new" expression whose head is not `HoldAllComplete`, it will check `UpValues` of *each* of its arguments, which is an $O(n)$ operation, where $n$ is the length of the expression. Of course, *Mathematica* is optimized to "remember" what expressions have already been checked and have not been modified since then (more precisely, *Mathemtica* somehow marks expressions as "not modified form the last evaluation" using hashes as far as I understand). For this reason, this will also run fast:

```
Do[Integrate[sum[[i]], x], {i, n}] // Timing
(*{0.078125, Null}*)
```

After the first evaluation of `sum` *Mathematica* "memories" that all `SubValues` of `sum`'s arguments have been checked and will not check them on later steps. This is not true if you modify `sum` during the evaluation: since `sum` has been modified, `SubValues` of its arguments need to be checked again.

But in (I hope) rare cases *Mathematica* can fail determining whether there is a need for evaluation, evaluating an expression even if it was not necessary, so one shouldn't rely on this feature too much.

Finally, the method proposed by @AlexeiBoulbitch does not involve modifying in place, and hence is efficient either.

```
psum = Partition[sum, n/10];
Do[
 Map[
  Integrate[#, x] &,
  psum[[i]]
],
{i, 1, 10}
]; // Timing
(*{0.078125, Null}*)
```

Although it requires extra memory for the partitioned list.

**P.S**

I am not a specialist in `Integrate`, but @AlexeiBoulbitch made an interesting remark, which is not related to handling long expressions but can be of use in your particular problem:

> I have one more comment. You did not show your expressions and I do not know, if they may depend on parameters. In the latter case, there can be a situation that in different domains of the parametric space the integral has different values, while in some has no value at all. Typically, in such a situation it takes a long time to evaluate such an integral. If, however, you fix the domain in the parametric space by using Assumptions, it is fast

**P.P.S.**

All this `SubValues` story is not applicable to `PackedArray`s as long as you perform only numerical operations which do not unpack it. But in your case you clearly use a symbolic expression.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:

A contrived sum.

```
n = 5;

sum = Plus @@ Table[x^i, {i, n}]
(* x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x^5 *)
```

Now we will convert sum to a list, integrate each of the terms separately and convert the list back into a sum.

```
sum[[0]] = List; sum
(* {x, x^2, x^3, x^4, x^5} *)

Do[sum[[i]] = Integrate[sum[[i]], x], {i, n}]

sum[[0]] = Plus; sum
(* x^2/2 + x^3/3 + x^4/4 + x^5/5 + x^6/6 *)
```

The above code does all its operations in-place without making copies and, thus, conserves memory. Perhaps you can apply this technique to your problem.

Comment: This code might be *extremely* inefficient unless you use `HoldComplete` head instead of `List`. Compare `Do[sum[[i]] = Integrate[sum[[i]], x], {i, n}] // Timing` with `Do[Integrate[sum[[i]], x], {i, n}] // Timing` for a very large `n`. So, it is NOT the same as the approach proposed by @AlexeiBoulbitch